# Is there any way to create dynamic array in scala? Means inserting values at run time?

Tags: arrays, scala, dynamic, size

```
var arr=Array.ofDim[Int](4,4)
arr(0)(0)(0)(0)=12
```

this is one way to insert elements in array. 
but if i need to initialize size of array dynamically or at run time. How can we do it in scala?

Comment: `new Array(size)` or `Array.ofDim(size)` (this method allows you to initialize multidimensional arrays).  What is your question as it seems you already know how to initialize an array?

Comment: This is runtime. Instead of 4 you can write whatever you wish.

Comment: @HemantChauhan does my [answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/46303557/5249621) work for you?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Here

```
val n = StdIn.readInt
val m = StdIn.readInt
val arr = Array.ofDim[Int](n, m)
arr(5)(15) = 1
println(arr.deep.mkString("\n"))
```

I created 2-dimensional array with sizes known only in runtime (I entered 10 and 20).

---

Or maybe you need `scala.collection.mutable.ArrayBuffer` if you're going to change sizes.

`ArrayBuffer[Int]` is 1-dimensional, `ArrayBuffer[ArrayBuffer[Int]]` is 2-dimensional etc.

```
val arr: ArrayBuffer[ArrayBuffer[Int]] = 
  ArrayBuffer.fill(10)(ArrayBuffer.fill(20)(0))

arr(5)(15) = 1
println(arr.mkString("\n"))

println

arr(5) += 1
arr += ArrayBuffer.fill[Int](25)(0)
println(arr.mkString("\n"))
```

Comment: what is this arr(5)(15)=1

Comment: I'm just illustrating how to work with `ArrayBuffer[ArrayBuffer[Int]]`. When I did `ArrayBuffer.fill ...` value of `arr(5)(15)` was 0, after `arr(5)(15)=1` it became 1.